# How to disable running Firefox as root without password Linux?

Tags: permissions

I'm new to using Linux. How to disable running Firefox as root without password in Linux? I want to take permission back.

I am probably clicking something, and now I can't take it back to normal, so if someone can help I will appreciate. I'm tried in google but only found post like someone want "run firefox as root as always without password".

Comment: @peterh not always in the unix-geek dialect.

Comment: @cas I don't think that the OP would be a Unix geek. But I tried to fix this post, but it is still not really clear to me, and it was only the smallest problem with it. The major problem with it, that I am not sure, if it was created by a Markov-chain, or it is a real problem.

Comment: the only sense I can make of the question is that the OP might have either changed the desktop icon that runs firefox so that it runs `sudo firefox` or run something like `chmod u+s /path/to/firefox`, or something like that..  In either case the answer is two-fold: "revert (i.e. undo)" and "don't do that".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever brought you to the realization that there might be something 'bad' about running firefox as root is to be commended. Whatever it was, keep reinforcing that.

Probably the best solution for you would be to tape a note on a corner of your computer display reminding you to NEVER, ***NEVER*** login to a graphical user session as root.